# openweather api current data doesnot match with forecast data

Tags: openweathermap

I am using Current weather data openweather api to display the Weather, Description, temperature, max temp, min temp, Wind speed, Wind direction in my application and it works  fine. I tried to use the 5 day / 3 hour forecast i see there is a mismatch in the information displayed in current weather data and 5 day / 3 hour forecast, for example i see in current weather data temperature for london is 9.3°C but if we check in 5 day / 3 hour forecast i am not able to find 9.3°C. Can anyone guide me whether the below API used is proper and anything you find.

Below is the URL being used to fetch the data

Current weather data: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&units=metric&APPID=c49f2a5b07ce03250befb407c4410be3

5 day / 3 hour forecast:http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London&units=metric&APPID=c49f2a5b07ce03250befb407c4410be3

Answer (score 1):

The should not match absolutely. The raw data that used for these APIs is a little bit different and the time gap is different.

Just use one of them specifically for forecast or current weather info.